# [R Shiny]: How to filter by time range on the x-axis and simultaneously have two different variables on the y axis in R Shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactive

I want to build a shiny app using Covid-19 data (https://data.europa.eu/euodp/de/data/dataset/covid-19-coronavirus-data) and I would like to show barplot with ggplot where you can see the development of worldwide cases or deaths over time. I would furthermore like to have a dateRangeInput in which you can set a time period. At the same time I have on the y axis either the possibility to choose from selectInput either the variable "cases" or "deaths". I can do this separately but I can't figure out how to have this in one final plot.
It works with the time range if I use this code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Covid-19 by Country"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "y", label = "Y-Axe:", 
                  choices=c("cases", "deaths"), 
                  selected = "cases"),
      dateRangeInput("datum", "Zeitraum auswählen", start = min(covid_worldwide$dateRep), end = max(covid_worldwide$dateRep), min = min(covid_worldwide$dateRep), max = max(covid_worldwide$dateRep), format = "dd.mm.yyyy", language = "de")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("covidPlot") 
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  s <- reactive({
   covid_worldwide %>%
      filter( 
        as.Date(dateRep) >= as.Date(input$datum[1]),
        as.Date(dateRep) <= as.Date(input$datum[2])
      )
  })
  output$covidPlot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data= s(), aes(x = dateRep, y = cases)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="red") + theme_classic() + xlab("Zeitraum") + ylab("Anzahl")
    }
  )}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It works also if I do not change the time period but give two different variables for the y-axis, see following code (the UI is the same as above):

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  s <- reactive({
  covid_worldwide %>%
      filter(
        as.Date(dateRep) >= as.Date(input$datum[1]),
        as.Date(dateRep) <= as.Date(input$datum[2])
      )
  })
  
  yvar <- reactive({
    if ( "cases" %in% input$y) return(covid_worldwide$cases)
    if ( "deaths" %in% input$y) return(covid_worldwide$deaths)
  })
  output$covidPlot <- renderPlot({
    
      ggplot(data= s(), aes(x = dateRep, y = yvar())) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="red") + theme_classic() + xlab("Zeitraum") + ylab("Anzahl")
    }
  )}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But if I then try to change the time period in the shiny app I receive this error: "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (26852): y"
Does anyone have an idea on how to make the two things in one ggplot barplot work? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to map `input$y` on `y` in your plotting code. Additionally as the input is a character it's convenient to switch to `aes_string` instead of `aes` as it allows to pass the variables as names or strings to `ggplot()`.

The first version does not work as you map `cases` on `y`. The second one does not work as your reactive `yvar` extracts a vector from the original unfiltered df. Therefore the length of `yvar` is greater than the number of rows of the filtered df or the length of your date variable.

```
output$covidPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data= s(), aes_string(x = "dateRep", y = input$y)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="red") + theme_classic() + xlab("Zeitraum") + ylab("Anzahl")
  }
```